# QGIS not rendering PostGis Geometry column correctly

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis, qgis

I'm currently storing a lot of data on a Azure SQL for Postgres instance. My table consists of columns like lat, lon, and geometry which is created using PostGis function

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat,lon),4326))
```

However, when I import the table into QGIS using a filter on an identifier column and between two timestamps the QGIS Query Builder clearly shows a decent number of records being returned. However, QGIS (I've tried Google Map, OpenStreetMap) renders the Geometry points near Africa (see screenshot below). Looking at some lat and lon pairs on maps.google.com that make up the geometry points, the location is completely different from what QGIS shows.

I've changed the CRS of the project, the Layers for the Map and the Coordinates (i.e. geometry points) to **4326**. But still all the data points show up near Africa.

Any ideas what may be causing this and how to resolve it?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostGIS convention is to pass longitude first (as X coordinate) and latitude second (as Y). So try

`ST_MakePoint(lon, lat, 4326)`

Comment: It indeed as simple as that. Thank you!